# How do agregate functions in MS Access effect 'odd' field types?

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate

I'm having trouble with MS Access. I have boolean and Memo type fields and I'm using aggregate functions (Group by etc). The Bools give information about a survey result, and the memo field explains the reasoning behind that result.

I've hit two minor hiccups,

1. **My booleans are displaying as 0 (unchecked) and -1 (checked)**
    I managed to revert them back to tick boxes (slightly more obvious what they are) but now they are back to numeric expressions, and I don't know what I did.
2. **My memo/boolean field behaves weirdly when comparing `FIRST`/`LAST`**
    Before, when I grouped by the memo field I had duplicates, the ones with a checked boolean tickbox came First, and were lined up with the memo field. When I apply `FIRST` logic it displays the 'last' of the duplicates, eg, with two 'duplicates' that only vary by the boolean and memo, `FIRST` displays duplicate 2. If I apply `LAST` logic it displays duplicate 1.

To clarify, when using `GROUP BY` it displayed as such:

```
Name|Risk? |Memo
Bob |Tick  |Description one
Bob |Untick|Description two
```

And when selecting the risk and memo field to only display FIRST I got:

```
Name|Risk? |Memo
Bob |0     |Description two
```

Which was not the first one out of the duplicates!

So I have to ask, how are agregated booleans displayed, and why do they get converted to 0/-1? And how are Booleans/Memo fields sorted using `FIRST`/`LAST` logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are saying, but zero (0) comes before minus one (-1), so the No (0) will be first. As for changing to 0,-1, they are not, that is what the field contains, anything else is format. If you are running a query, you can add a format to suit:

```
 SELECT Format([ayesno],"Yes/No") FROM table
```

More: [Format Property - Yes/No Data Type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/format-property-yes-no-data-type-HA001232749.aspx)

The bottom corner shows Top 1, which is what I suspect you want.

```
sSQL = "SELECT t.Comment, t.TickThis " _
& "FROM Table2 t " _
& "WHERE t.ID IN ( " _
& "SELECT Top 1 ID FROM Table2 t2 " _
& "WHERE t2.Comment=t1.Comment " _
& "ORDER BY t2.TickThis Desc, t2.Comment) "
```

[image: Last, min, max]

Comment: My confusion came as when the boolean was grouped, the -1 came first order wise, and at the time was displayed as a tick. After selecting `FIRST` on that field, I got the last one.

Comment: That is the problem with imposed formats. I have no idea how you got the tick.

Comment: Formatting a YesNo data type in SQL as per my example should work in 2003, the link information I would avoid in queries, because it is an Access property and could cause problems, but it should be fine for forms.

Comment: BTW You will have problems with memo data types and queries, they will often be truncated to 255 characters.

Comment: I have an issue where this is messed up by Aggregate functions. Which order should they be in, as it stands it seems `SELECT LAST(Format([ayesno],"Yes/No")) FROM table ` and `SELECT Format(LAST([ayesno]),"Yes/No") FROM table` both give me just a column full of 'Yes'

Comment: What is it you want? Do you want to extract the the yes comments from the table?

Comment: I simply want to display the -1 as a yes, and the 0 as a no. I fear there may have been a more fundemental issue for why I was seeing only yeses

Comment: Run a simple select with a format and see of it is giving you what you expect.